# compactMapValues not filtering nil values

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift5

`compactMapValues` on a dictionary returns dictionary with the `nil` values.

I am using the method as suggested by most of the documentation out there. `compactMapValues { $0 }`

```
extension Dictionary where Key == RequestParameter {

    func nilFiltered() -> [RequestParameter: Any] {
        return compactMapValues { $0 }
    }

}
```

RequestParameter is a enum and I am calling the method like..

```
[RequestParameter.param1: "value1", RequestParameter.param2: nil]. nilFiltered()
```

The necessary filtering is not happening. Is this is a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: plz add some example or your last stage of code where your are stuck

Comment: Updated with some code

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/add-compactmapvalues-to-dictionary/8741/15

Comment: @downvoter Downvote for?

Comment: here comes the upvoter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just return `$0`, that adds a level of optionality  The return value of

```swift
[RequestParameter.param1: "value1", .param2: nil]
```

is a `[RequestParameter: String?]`, which introduces double-optionality. Either do this:

```swift
extension Dictionary {
  func nilFiltered<Wrapped>() -> [Key: Any] where Value == Wrapped? {
    compactMapValues { $0 }
  }
}
```

or if you don't actually need `Any`, avoid that rubbish!

```swift
extension Dictionary {
  func nilFiltered<Wrapped>() -> [Key: Wrapped] where Value == Wrapped? {
    compactMapValues { $0 }
  }
}
```

Here's an alternative that I don't like.

```swift
extension Dictionary {
  func nilFiltered() -> [Key: Any] {
    compactMapValues {
      if case nil as Value? = $0 {
        return nil
      }

      return $0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I went with the first implementation as I wanted it to be Any and it worked as expected! Can you help me understand what exactly was the issue? I did not get the double-optionality..

Comment: The runtime internally knows that it was a optional property as I was passing optionals. How can it not get filtered unless we specify Value == Wrapped? is my question

Comment: It is getting compacted. It's just impossible for a `Value` to be `Value?.none`. Think about it; how would setting a value to `nil` remove the key otherwise? What you've got are `??.some(nil)`s, not `?.nones`.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response.. Still trying to understand this better; here is the actual implementation of compactMapValues in Swift https://github.com/SwiftScream/ScreamNetworking/commit/b56988eeccd0997f248d333b3fcc7d6728507cd0 Looking at the implementation, the reduce function should not miss the Optional value of the Value item. Right? Even if we don't specify the where Value == Wrapped? is what I am saying..

Comment: Your `transform` is `(Value?) -> Value??`. Mine is `(Value?) -> Value?`. Without telling the compiler somehow to compact single-optionals, all of your values are just going to get wrapped in another optional. It doesn't matter if they're `nil`; the wrapping optional won't be. Just don't use optionals as dictionary values and you can save yourself confusion.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer and the clarifications :)

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is the following:

```
let dictionary =  (["key1": 1,
                    "key2": nil,
                    "key3": "anotherValue",
                    "key4": nil] as [String: Any?])
                    .compactMapValues { $0 }

print(dictionary)
```

This will make output:

```
["key1": 1, "key3": "anotherValue"]
```